# foreach loop with DOMDocument on PHP

Tags: php

This code doesn't get out any thing, even the `0`.

```
<?php
     $html = '<a href="abc" >Hello world!</a><a href="abcdef" >Hello  </a>';
     $html = '<div>' . $html . '</div>';
     $doc = new DOMDocument;
     $doc->loadHTML($html);
     $links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
     foreach ($links as $link){
         echo "0";
         echo $dom->saveHTML($link->getAttribute('href');
     }
     // Outputs: "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
 ?>
```

Comment: from where `$dom` is comming?

Comment: code sample is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to drop the `->item(0)` following your `getElementsByTagName` call or you will just get the first anchor element in `$links` (which is why the `foreach` does not do what you want it to). The `saveHTML` call will also have to be removed.

```
$html = '<a href="abc" >Hello world!</a><a href="abcdef" >Hello  </a>';
$html = '<div>' . $html . '</div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Drop the ->item(0)
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link){
    // Remove saveHTML call
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$html = '<a href="abc" >Hello world!</a><a href="abcdef" >Hello  </a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: just add -- echo $link->getAttribute('href');